# Java: Delete newline which is already printed

Tags: java, io

Given the Java Code:

```
System.out.println("hello"); 
System.out.println();
//insert here
System.out.prinln(" world");
```

Is there a way to delete the new line where we insert something into "//insert here" without modifying the rest of the Code such that the Output will go from:

```
Hello

World
```

into:

```
Hello World
```

I already search for solutions for example `print('\b')` or `Thread.sleep(1000)`; but the first one does exactly the opposite of what I want and the latter just crushes everything.

Edit: I know that one could simply use `print` istead

Comment: I don't think so. Why don't you use a correct string format to begin with?

Comment: using System.out.print instead and use System.out.println when you need a new line

Comment: It's part of a bigger question I just tried to reduce it to it's bare bones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no really portable way to do it, because not every terminal type supports cursor movement up. However, you can try ASCII control sequences. For example `ESC [2A` moves cursor 2 lines up. Unfortunately, positioning cursor after the printed 'Hello' is impossible without knowing the length of 'Hello' - the information about how many characters are already printed on this line is not available.

Comment: Ty I think Im going to ask my teacher how to solve the issue in my exercise because deleting something seemes to me to be the only way but since this is very difficult Im probably misunderstanding something

Answer (score 0):

you can use System.out.print instead println

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).